# MVC4 Application Layout - Difference between localhost and published version

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

We have developed a MVC4 application. When running locally, it works well. But when it is published to IIS, the layout completely changes and the screens look weird. Do I have to do any configuration changes or any settings change in IIS.

IIS Version 7.5 
IE Version 9.

Comment: "the screens look weird" - what exactly does this mean? Can you provide a screenshot or a better description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if IE is running in compatibility mode.  IE has a tendency to do this for intranet sites.  Go to Tools -> Compatibility View settings and look at the "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" checkbox.